# Keyup event doesn't fire to display error message and disable button

Tags: angular

I have an on screen form on which I need to asses the users entry in real-time to make sure that the `pageName` they type in doesn't exist in the `navbarMenuOptions` array. If it does, I want to toggle the stage of `displayName` and `displaySaveButton`. However, I am seeing a strange error wherein the keyup event doesn't fire. How can fix it?

**Typescript**

```
pageName: string;
displayError: boolean = false;
disableSaveButton: boolean = false;
navbarMenuOptions = ['Home', 'About', 'Features', 'Contact'];

validatePageName() {
    if (!this.pageName) {
      this.displayError = false;
      this.disableSaveButton = true;
    } else {
      for(let i = 0; i < this.navbarMenuOptions.length; i++) {
        if(this.pageName.toLowerCase() === this.navbarMenuOptions[i].toLowerCase()) {
          this.displayError = true;
          this.disableSaveButton = true;
        } else {
          this.displayError = false;
          this.disableSaveButton = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="displayError">
    A page with this name already exists.
  </div>
  Please enter a name for your new page.
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pageName"></label><input class="form-control" id="pageName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="pageName" (keyup)="validatePageName()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" [disabled]="disableSaveButton">Save</button>&nbsp;
    <button (click)="onCloseButtonClick()" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code ([stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-keyup-disable)):

```
validatePageName() {
    if (!this.pageName || this.pageName.trim() == '') {
      this.displayError = false;
      this.disableSaveButton = true;
    } else {
      for(let i = 0; i < this.navbarMenuOptions.length; i++) {
        if(this.pageName.toLowerCase() === this.navbarMenuOptions[i].toLowerCase()) {
          this.displayError = true;
          this.disableSaveButton = true;
          break;
        } else {
          this.displayError = false;
          this.disableSaveButton = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing you are adding something like a space and expecting that it will disable.

I also added a break to make your error message work as the for loop will not work for true otherwise.

Comment: I have 2 points to clarify, 1) How a `break` statement is doing the magic? When I commented the `break` line, it's not working, I am confused and shocked that it's not working as expected. 2) When, I debugged and checked, the code is reaching the `if` condition, but still not disabling the `button`?

Comment: If you don't break, then on the first iteration i.e. with Home it will disable the button, then it will go in again in the other three and enable. If you try with 'Contact' which is the last, it will work even without the break.

Comment: Basically, it assigns true, false, false, false if you don't use the beak.

Comment: Yep, correct. I just missed it. A small mistake but a huge price to pay for. :)